# How to read return code of certain command in a chain

Tags: shell, sh

I am running a chain of commands separated by `;`. How can I check return code of individual commands? for eg: `db2 connect to mydb;db2 list tables;db2 terminate`
I am using `sh` shebang.

Comment: Store all of your commands in an array and store each exit status in another array while executing commands from first array to be able to retrieve it by index later.

Comment: Assuming you want the exit status to avoid, for example, listing tables when the connection failed, you just want to use `&&` instead of `;`: `db2 connect to mydb && db2 list tables && db2 terminate`.